# Adjective + adjective without “and”

Tags: adjectives

> They said hello and I felt my face turn bright red.

“Bright” and “red” are predicative adjectives, but why isn’t there “and” between them?

Comment: "Bright" is not predicative here, but just _part of_ the predicative AdjP "bright red" that has "red" as head and "bright" as modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Red" here is a predicate adjective. It modifies "face" by means of the linking verb "turn."

"Bright" *can* be used as a predicate adjective. It works that way in each of the following:

> 1. The lamp is bright.
> 2. The sun is hot and bright.

In #2, "hot" and "bright" are distinct qualities of "the sun."

But in your sentence, "bright" is not a predicate adjective. It does not modify "face." Rather, it modifies "red." It tells us more about the color.

If you look at a chart of the color red, with white at one end and black at the other, bright red will be roughly in the center. Dark red will be closer to the black end. Light red will be closed to the white end.

Exactly what part of speech "bright" is when it modifies colors is [subject to debate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315215/bright-part-of-speech), and I will not repeat here what you can read elsewhere—you might even find the discussion boring.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jefrey Carney's answer and @BillJ's comment, there're quite a few other adjectives modifying the color--its value/intensity--the most common being *dark, deep, intense, rich, light, pale*.